# linux-oem-22.04a does not load MOK certificates

Tags: kernel, secure-boot

I started to test the oem kernel on ubuntu 22.04 jammy. Doing so I wondered why all my dkms modules don't load when secure boot is active although they are correctly signed. After investigating quite a while I found that the MOK certificates are not loaded during boot.
This is from journalctl -k with the hwe kernel (currently 5.15.0-33-generic) where everything is fine:

```
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: Loaded X.509 cert 'Build time autogenerated kernel key: cee583cd7127fcb5e727bd8fee80ccf9b6c19422'
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Live Patch Signing: 14df34d1a87cf37625abec039ef2bf521249b969'
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Kernel Module Signing: 88f752e560a1e0737e31163a466ad7b70a850c19'
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: blacklist: Loading compiled-in revocation X.509 certificates
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing: 61482aa2830d0ab2ad5af10b7250da9033ddcef0'
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: zswap: loaded using pool lzo/zbud
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: Key type ._fscrypt registered
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: Key type .fscrypt registered
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: Key type fscrypt-provisioning registered
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: Key type trusted registered
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: Key type encrypted registered
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: AppArmor: AppArmor sha1 policy hashing enabled
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: integrity: Loading X.509 certificate: UEFI:db
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'Dell Inc.: Dell Bios DB Key: 637fa7a9f74471b406de0511557071fd41dd5487'
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: integrity: Loading X.509 certificate: UEFI:db
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'Dell Inc.: Dell Bios FW Aux Authority 2018: dd4df7c3f5ce7e5a77847915abc3>
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: integrity: Loading X.509 certificate: UEFI:db
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'Microsoft Windows Production PCA 2011: a92902398e16c49778cd90f99e4f9ae17>
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: integrity: Loading X.509 certificate: UEFI:db
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'Microsoft Corporation UEFI CA 2011: 13adbf4309bd82709c8cd54f316ed522988a>
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: integrity: Revoking X.509 certificate: UEFI:dbx
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: blacklist: Revoked X.509 cert 'Microsoft Windows PCA 2010: d14fa98a0708cef4241898e500fff3d6791d37bc'
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: integrity: Loading X.509 certificate: UEFI:MokListRT (MOKvar table)
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Master Certificate Authority: ad91990bc22ab1f517048c23b66>
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: integrity: Loading X.509 certificate: UEFI:MokListRT (MOKvar table)
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'silvershadow Secure Boot Module Signature key: d0f162f7b494c7188637ff51f>
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: Loading compiled-in module X.509 certificates
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: Loaded X.509 cert 'Build time autogenerated kernel key: cee583cd7127fcb5e727bd8fee80ccf9b6c19422'
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: ima: Allocated hash algorithm: sha1
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: ima: No architecture policies found
```

And this is from `journalctl -k` with the oem kernel (currently 5.17.0-1006-oem) where the MOK certificates are not loaded:

```
Mai 24 23:53:20 silvershadow kernel: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
Mai 24 23:53:20 silvershadow kernel: Loaded X.509 cert 'Build time autogenerated kernel key: f588ef5f31df3af9af115966e412ed048604418c'
Mai 24 23:53:20 silvershadow kernel: Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Live Patch Signing: 14df34d1a87cf37625abec039ef2bf521249b969'
Mai 24 23:53:20 silvershadow kernel: Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Kernel Module Signing: 88f752e560a1e0737e31163a466ad7b70a850c19'
Mai 24 23:53:20 silvershadow kernel: blacklist: Loading compiled-in revocation X.509 certificates
Mai 24 23:53:20 silvershadow kernel: Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing: 61482aa2830d0ab2ad5af10b7250da9033ddcef0'
Mai 24 23:53:20 silvershadow kernel: zswap: loaded using pool lzo/zbud
Mai 24 23:53:20 silvershadow kernel: Key type ._fscrypt registered
Mai 24 23:53:20 silvershadow kernel: Key type .fscrypt registered
Mai 24 23:53:20 silvershadow kernel: Key type fscrypt-provisioning registered
Mai 24 23:53:20 silvershadow kernel: Key type trusted registered
Mai 24 23:53:20 silvershadow kernel: Key type encrypted registered
Mai 24 23:53:20 silvershadow kernel: AppArmor: AppArmor sha1 policy hashing enabled
Mai 24 23:53:20 silvershadow kernel: integrity: Loading X.509 certificate: UEFI:db
Mai 24 23:53:20 silvershadow kernel: integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'Dell Inc.: Dell Bios DB Key: 637fa7a9f74471b406de0511557071fd41dd5487'
Mai 24 23:53:20 silvershadow kernel: integrity: Loading X.509 certificate: UEFI:db
Mai 24 23:53:20 silvershadow kernel: integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'Dell Inc.: Dell Bios FW Aux Authority 2018: dd4df7c3f5ce7e5a77847915abc3>
Mai 24 23:53:20 silvershadow kernel: integrity: Loading X.509 certificate: UEFI:db
Mai 24 23:53:20 silvershadow kernel: integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'Microsoft Windows Production PCA 2011: a92902398e16c49778cd90f99e4f9ae17>
Mai 24 23:53:20 silvershadow kernel: integrity: Loading X.509 certificate: UEFI:db
Mai 24 23:53:20 silvershadow kernel: integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'Microsoft Corporation UEFI CA 2011: 13adbf4309bd82709c8cd54f316ed522988a>
Mai 24 23:53:20 silvershadow kernel: integrity: Revoking X.509 certificate: UEFI:dbx
Mai 24 23:53:20 silvershadow kernel: blacklist: Revoked X.509 cert 'Microsoft Windows PCA 2010: d14fa98a0708cef4241898e500fff3d6791d37bc'
Mai 24 23:53:20 silvershadow kernel: Loading compiled-in module X.509 certificates
Mai 24 23:53:20 silvershadow kernel: Loaded X.509 cert 'Build time autogenerated kernel key: f588ef5f31df3af9af115966e412ed048604418c'
Mai 24 23:53:20 silvershadow kernel: ima: Allocated hash algorithm: sha1
Mai 24 23:53:20 silvershadow kernel: ima: No architecture policies found
```

The part where the MOK certificates are loaded (in 5.15.0-33-generic):

```
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: integrity: Loading X.509 certificate: UEFI:MokListRT (MOKvar table)
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Master Certificate Authority: ad91990bc22ab1f517048c23b66>
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: integrity: Loading X.509 certificate: UEFI:MokListRT (MOKvar table)
Mai 25 00:14:56 silvershadow kernel: integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'silvershadow Secure Boot Module Signature key: d0f162f7b494c7188637ff51f>
```

is missing when booting 5.17.0-1006-oem.

How can that be???

This is on a Dell XPS-17 9710, latest BIOS updates (1.81), latest jammy updates. silvershadow is the hostname ;-)

If you need any more information please let me know

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: Not me but the kernel developers as it seems. After quite a while there came an update and after that it worked. I don't know which one it was because I did not follow the topic anymore until I tried it out of curiosity a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

I'm testing in linux-image-5.17.0-1003-oem (ubuntu 22.04)
and i  believe this commit matters:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/92ad19559ea9a8ec6f158480934ae26ebfe2c14f

Skip load mok list depending on `arch_ima_get_secureboot` which rely on config `CONFIG_IMA_SECURE_AND_OR_TRUSTED_BOOT`.

However in linux-image-5.17.0-1003 CONFIG_IMA_SECURE_AND_OR_TRUSTED_BOOT is unset, thus kernel always skip laod mok list.